# Magento 2 Header Sign In Sign Out Issue

Tags: full-page-cache, magento2.3.0, varnish, magento2.3.3, redis

I have ultimo theme on magento 2.3.3 with redis and varnish. After Sign Out the link still displays Sign Out and vice versa. Becomes normal after cache is flushed. looks like cache issue. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Share more details with screenshots as well some code structures.

Comment: just share my details of sites so I can check code etc otherwise which code used in that theme I can not understand.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-3-add-custom-login-and-logout-button/td-p/121047

Comment: Please try using knockout js, please check my ans for more information.

Comment: Yes, You can add cacheable = false in header in layout xml file.

Answer (score 6):

Please try the following way using knockout js.
you can add following code in your .phtml file, this will help you to resolve login issue while the cache is enabled

```
<ul data-bind="scope: 'customer'" class="header links">
    <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
        <li><a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account'); ?>">My account</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>">Log out</a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().firstname -->
        <li><a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/create'); ?>">Create an account</a></li>
        <li class="authorization-link"><a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/login/'); ?>">Sign in</a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please check and let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: I don't want to add any additional code. Ultimo theme does what it is supposed to. I believe it is a configuration issue. Because things become alright when I flush cache.

Comment: @Zoya can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

The FPC system relies on sections.xml files that defines when some data in Magento can be renewed.

For instance, if you open the file `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/frontend/sections.xml`, you will see many action paths that tell magento to renew the section data.

Now, I don't know your theme, but it may be possible the theme uses a different url end point to login/logout your customer and this path would need to be added in a sections.xml file in a custom module your would need to create

Comment: Thanks. Where can I see the action names please in Ultimo theme? Is there any keyword I can grep for?

Comment: Open your browser console, check preserve logs and clear the logs in the console. Then hit the login widget in the theme and find the call in the network tab from your developer tools (in chrome that is)

Answer (score -2):

Can you please use `Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` instead of `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

```
$customerSes = $this->sessionFactory->create();
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

}
```

Comment: Which file do i modify? I am using Ultimo theme

Comment: Sign Out and Sign In link is working on based on isLoggedIn function, so can you please check file location and check isLoggedIn function object and change object class.

Comment: Have you implement my suggestion ??